# Is there a word for "about to be mentioned"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm curious whether there is a word for it or not.

For example: "The problems that will be mentioned are going to be analyzed..."

And: "The xxx problems are going to be analyzed".

Comment: "The problems that will be mentioned" are going to be actually mentioned **immediately** after this text?

Comment: I would tend to say "the problems to be discussed" or some such, if the "mention" will be more than cursory.  Otherwise I'd say "the problems we will enumerate" or some such, where they will basically just be listed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **"ensuing"** or **"following"**

> - ensue - "to come at a later time" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ensue), to follow in order; come afterward, esp. in immediate succession [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ensue)

Comment: Yes, this sounds very good.

Comment: Following sounds OK. "Ensuing problems" would make me think the problems themselves were ensuing from something.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to list the problems *immediately* after this text, then I would go with Centaurus's suggestion of "following".

> The following problems are going to be analyzed in this report
>
> - Problem 1
> - Problem 2
> - Problem 3

But if the list won't appear until somewhat later in the text, you could consider  "enumerated shortly".

> The problems that will be enumerated shortly are going to be analyzed in accordance with...